# Access Requests Method within Celery Task

Tags: django, python-requests, celery

Is it possible to access the requests.POST/GET methods within a celery task that's in a django project?  I've read that it's not possible because celery can't serialized the requests JSON objects.  Other than taking the data from the requests.POST['data'] object and passing them to the celery task, are there any other work arounds?

```
def index(request):
    task = run_tasks.delay(request) # I would like to pass the request data to the task
    return render(request, 'example/index.html', {'task_id': task.task_id})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.urlencode(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.urlencode) to convert it to a string object and back:

```
def index(request):
    run_tasks.delay(data=request.GET.urlencode())
    return render(request, 'example/index.html', {'task_id': task.task_id})
```

at the receiving end, you can then reconstruct the `QueryDict` with:

```
from django.http import QueryDict

def some_task(data):
    GET = QueryDict(data)
    # work with GET …
    pass
```